# Viscosity and Density

Tags: kinematics

So I'm reading my textbook and it says that that magnitude of air resistance $f(v)$ can be given as a taylor expansion:

$$f(v) = bv + c^2v = f_{\text{linear}} + f_{\text{quadratic}}$$

The linear term, $bv$ is related to the viscosity of the medium while the quadratic term is related to the density of the medium. If something is more dense, shouldn't it be more viscous as well? Or are viscosity and density not related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in general, viscosity and density are not related. For example, for [gases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Gases), we have:

> Maxwell's calculations show that the viscosity coefficient is proportional to the density, the mean free path, and the mean velocity of the atoms. On the other hand, the mean free path is inversely proportional to the density. *So an increase in density due to an increase in pressure doesn't result in any change in viscosity.*

Alternatively, to directly disprove your assertion *"If something is more dense, shouldn't it be more viscous as well?"*, we need look no further than oil and water: Since most oils float on water, their density must be less than that of water, and yet, oils are undeniably [*more viscous*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Other_substances) than water.